# How to filter by two fields using a single exposed filter in Views?

Tags: views

I have a view listing nodes. I added 2 exposed filters. One is **Content: title** and the other is **Content:Body**. Then I have 2 input fields to enter some keyword to do searchs.

I need to have **just one** field and do the search in both fields: title and body. Can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you could either:

- Use the *Global: Combine fields filter* which allows you to choose two fields (out of those already added to the display as a normal field) to filter on. The filter can be exposed, its operator changed, etc. like normal. Views warns *This filter doesn't work for very special field handlers.*
- Use the *Search: Search Terms* filter. This uses search.module's data to do the query (check out the *search index* build mode).

Comment: thanks. I used the Search: Search Terms filter method and get it working properly.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to combine the First name and Last name from the user object to filter the view. Global: Combine fields did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the search terms that works.

It search both title and the body and display the result.